# Localhost Spring Boot service not found

Tags: rest, spring-boot

I am studying Spring Cloud and I am developing a study project.

I create a project that represents a simple REST API using Spring Boot and I run this in localhost.

I also created another project API Gateway, this one gets the request coming and calls the REST API, I am also running this one in localhost.

When I run the REST API and send a request to it, it responds properly, but if I send the request to API Gateway when API Gateway tries to call the REST API using RestTemplate it is getting this exception:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: No instances available for localhost

Both services are running in localhost.

Do anyone knows what is the cause of this error?

Comment: You need to add more details. how's your code? is a microservice app? do you have a server discovery?

Comment: Could you please share more details and code

Comment: I am trying to develop this example: https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-cloud/microservices-monitoring/

I created the first and the second application and tried to test.

Comment: Please update this question to be technically focused on a specific problem. Add more details about your current implementation and desired output. Also share any debugging information that would be helpful to others here.